# Post-hoc power calculation for AUC analysis, to evaluate a new diagnostic test in a cohort

Tags: statistical-power, auc, diagnosis

I need some urgent advice for a grant application. I am evaluating a new diagnostic test and at the last minute a Professor has offered me the dataset from a completed prospective study of the disease my test diagnoses. He wants me to check if his data is adequately powered to achieve and AUC of 0.75.

The cohort is n=318 and the prevalence of the disease is 50%.

Can this be done - is it scientifically sound? Does this qualify as post-hoc power calculation?

Answer (score 0):

I am under the impression that yes it would qualify as a post-hoc power calculation given the analyst here would perform the power analysis after the sample size is determined. However, if it feasible and/or ethical to further recruit participants, then the situation becomes more gray as the analysis would could then determine the suitable cohort size. Apologies; yet I would not be able to answer your other questions.